# How to get install path in YAML

Tags: kubernetes, openshift, kubernetes-pod

I installed keycloak in Redhat openshift and the yaml file link is below:
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/latest/openshift-examples/keycloak.yaml
what I am confused is that I can not find the full path where the keycloak installed in pod.

Can anyone help me out to explain where it config it the yaml?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please have a look at the keycloak image manifest to get more details on where exactly the keycloak is getting installed within container.

https://quay.io/repository/keycloak/keycloak/manifest/sha256:64fb81886fde61dee55091e6033481fa5ccdac62ae30a4fd29b54eb5e97df6a9

As per what i see from manifest JBOSS_HOME points to below location in manifest

`JBOSS_HOME=/opt/jboss/keycloak`

Also, i think you are trying to find the install location in the yaml file but there is no reference to install path in yaml file using env variables as far as i could see which might override the location defined in the Docker image file. Hope this helps